# Конфликтуют eslint и prettier

Tags: eslint, prettier

Есть функция

```
(function bar(number) {
    console.log(number);
}(15));
```

в eslint указано:

```
"wrap-iife": ["error", "outside"]
```

Проблема в том, что при срабатывании prettier функция превращается в

```
(function bar(number) {
        console.log(number);
    })(15);
```

И eslint выдает ошибку. Вот как сказать prettier, что нужно вызов поместить внутрь скобок `}(15))`? Что-то не могу найти такой настройки у них.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В последнее время не вижу необходимости использовать prettier. Не смотря на то, что они выполняют несколько разные функции с eslint, тем не менее, elsint хорошо справляется с работой по форматированию кода и может быть использован без prettier даже в крупных проектах.

На крайний случай есть плагин eslint-prettier.